# Insert words with newline character from function input to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a condition below. 
pop function in button input has line 1 followed by newline Line2.
When I click on button to javascript it pops error " Unexpected token ILLEGAL " in Console.

Value inside pop() of button is generated dynamically. I get this error only if I have a new line char in the input text.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function pop(valu)
{
alert("here"+valu);
document.getElementById('box').innnerHTML = valu;
}

</script>

<button onclick="pop('Line 1
Line 2')"> Click </button>
<textarea id='box'></textarea>
```

Backend is PHP.

Is there any way to achieve this on foreground ? or should I make any changes of inserting values to DB ?

I directly store the values in DB with newline character.

Comment: are you getting 'Line 1
Line 2' value from PHP ?

Comment: Use `\n` for newlines.

Comment: or `nl2br()` if it is PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @chandresh_cool Yes I get Line1 Line2 from PHP. But Line1 and Line2 are in two saperate lines.

Comment: @Prashanth Then check my answer. It should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is use to [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function in PHP side

```
nl2br($yournewlinestring);
```

function of PHP to convert newline to enter a new line for \n

But before storing convert your html line breaks in php like this

```
$_POST['xyz'] = preg_replace('/(?:\r\n|[\r\n])/', PHP_EOL, $_POST['xyz'] );
```

Comment: This is fine, my $_POST['xyz'] = "Line1 <NEXTLINE> Line2". I don't have any \n char in my input. How do I convert it to \n char.

Comment: then where do you get line2?

Comment: This is fine, my $_POST['xyz'] = "Line1 <NEXTLINE> Line2". I don't have any \n char in my input. How do I convert it to \n char.

Comment: Use this before stroing  $_POST['xyz']  = preg_replace('/(?:\r\n|[\r\n])/', PHP_EOL, $_POST['xyz'] );

Comment: @Prashanth use the regular expression which I gave it should preserve your line breaks while storing in db.

Comment: <NEXTLINE> doesn't imply \n. Its just a next line without any \n. Plz help me out. I receive input from TEXTAREA to $_POST. In TEXTAREA when I type ENTER, it will go to new line. And when I receive it in $_POST there is no char like \n, its just next line received. what should I do now..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30114/discussion-between-chandresh-cool-and-prashanth)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the newline characters, just do something like:

```
<?php $pop_variable = str_replace("\n", '\n', $pop_variable); ?>
<button onclick='pop("<?php echo htmlentities($pop_variable, ENT_QUOTES) ?>")' />
```

Remember to also run htmlentities to escape the quotes.

I do think this is doing too much in HTML, though. It might be more beneficial to store this in a PHP array and then `json_encode()` it. That way you don't have to do the above or take into account what happens when a " or ' is in the $pop_variable and might also be expandable if you wanted to add more buttons (of course, this depends on your use case).

Example:

```
<script>
function pop(valu) {
    // Should do some error checking to ensure pop_var is set
    document.getElementById('box').innnerHTML = pop_var[valu];
}
var pop_var = <?php echo json_encode(['button1' => "Line 1\nLine2", 'button1' => "Another Line 1\nAnother line with ' single quotes..."]);
</script>

<button onclick="pop('button1')">Click</button>
<button onclick="pop('button2')">Click</button>
<textarea id='box'></textarea>
```